# Why does my code run when it is not supposed to?

Tags: discord.js

```js
if (command == "lookup") {
    var user = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
    Blocked.forEach(bl => {
        if (message.author.id == bl) {
            message.reply("You have been blocked from using commands.")
            IsBlocked = 1
        }
        if (IsBlocked == 0) {
            rblxAPI.getUserIdFromUsername(user).then(found => {
                found.getStatus().then(stat => {
                    found.getFriendsCount().then(count => {
                        let rblxLookup = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setTitle("Lookup of: " + found.name)
                            .setDescription("User ID: " + found.id + " \n User Description: " + stat + " \n User Friends Count: " + count)
                        message.channel.send(rblxLookup)
                    })
                })
            }).catch(console.error());
        }
    })
}
```

So this is my code and when the user is blocked it still continues with the script. I get no errors. Why does this happen?

Comment: because you don't `return` where you check if the user is blocked.

Comment: It also does not run the actual script if they are not blocked either

Comment: I presume `Blocked` is an array with just the user ID in it? You could just get rid of `IsBlocked` and just have an if else block instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return where you check if they are blocked. Here is my guess on fixing it:

```js
if (command == "lookup") {
    var user = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
    Blocked.forEach(bl => {
        if (message.author.id == bl) {
            message.reply("You have been blocked from using commands.")
            IsBlocked = 1
            // I think you could just return here to end it if the user is blocked
            return;
        }
        if (IsBlocked == 0) {
            rblxAPI.getUserIdFromUsername(user).then(found => {
                found.getStatus().then(stat => {
                    found.getFriendsCount().then(count => {
                        let rblxLookup = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setTitle("Lookup of: " + found.name)
                            .setDescription("User ID: " + found.id + " \n User Description: " + stat + " \n User Friends Count: " + count)
                        message.channel.send(rblxLookup)
                    })
                })
            }).catch(console.error());
        }
    })
}
```

But i might just be stupid right now.

Comment: thats exactly what you need to do

Comment: https://hello-losers.is-inside.me/9pMM4RFq.mp4 That is what happens

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is @Sprocx. That looks like I would expect it to.